# Navigating between divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my asp.net mvc application I have a modal popup.In modal popup i have three divs displayed like tabs.each div has buttons "Next","Back".on click of these buttons i want to navigate between these divs

sample code

```
<div id="Div1">

     <ul>
        <li><a id="btnone" href="#OneTab">one</a></li>
        <li><a id="btTwo" href="#TwoTab">Two</a></li>
        <li><a id="btnThree" href="#ThreeTab">Three</a></li>

     </ul>

<div id="OneTab>
<input id="btnNext Type="button/>
<input id="btnBack Type="button/>
</div>
<div id="TwoTab>
</div>
<div>
```

Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: Add some code please to let us know how your taps actually work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  foloowing line of code on "Onclick" event of button
$('#Div1').tabs("select", tabid);
Here tabid is the id of the tab on which you want to navigate
The code change done is 
as below